# How to update my BB10 App without changing package name

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I am using my android project to create .bar files for bb 10 here I have one problem every time I need to change the package name as only then in bb10 device the builds get replaced. But here if I keep on changing the package name how to replace the app with the next version as the device would take it as a new app.But I want the old version to  get replaced when I give a new update on BB Appworld.

Does anyone have solution for this?

Comment: Do you update your version code in the manifest? After a update of version code the app should be replaced on the app store. You should never change the package name!